# How can I convert BitmapImage to Icon?

Tags: c#, bitmapimage

In my application I have to send a `List<MenuItem>` to my shell extension in WCF. These MenuItems are composed of an icon and a label. The type of the icon is `System.Drawing.Icon` but I have to work from `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`.
Is there a way to convert `BitmapImage` to `Icon` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My thoughts:

First convert your BitmapImage to a Bitmap

[Converting BitmapImage to Bitmap and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484357/converting-bitmapimage-to-bitmap-and-vice-versa)

then save as an Icon file

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/4a10d440-707f-48d7-865b-1d8804faf649/

Hope this helps!

Comment: `bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Icon)` throw an ArgumentNullException with the ImageFormat parameter. So I used this method in place that works : `Icon.FromHandle(((Bitmap)bitmap).GetHicon())` but there is a loss of color and they are reversed.

Comment: Is there any color loss if you save it as bmp or png file?

Answer (score 0):

Haven’t created icons myself this way but perhaps you could benefit from going from Graphics to Icon. Then you can select interpolation mode (which perhaps could be nice). See an example here: http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1684.htm