# WPF NotifyIcon problems

Tags: c#, wpf, notifyicon

Hi i have some parser error when im trying to add icon to NotifyIcon. This one works fine:

```
System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();

ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Documents\\Visual Studio
2012\\Projects\\Pies\\Pies\\main.ico");
```

But when I'm trying to do it in this way:

```
ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("main.ico");
```

It returns some strange ParserError. I added main.ico to the project. When im adding images in xaml I'm just using "/image/image.jpg" but this don't want to work in this way. Do yuo know why ?

Comment: That "strange ParserError" probably reads like Greek to you and you have absolutely no idea what it means.  But tells *us* exactly what the problem is.  Best to not assume we'll be as confuzzled about the error message as you are.

Comment: If yuo want to see all error msg, go to VS2012>new project>wpf C#, add some icon, copy those 2 lanes into public MainWindow().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, that you are trying to use WinForms control in WPF project. And [icon class from WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.drawing.icon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't support pack URIs.

Since you want to store your image in your assembly, you can't get it as WinForms Icon easily. WPF usually works with [ImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.media.imagesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and you can convert it to WF icon ([How can I convert BitmapImage to Icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247516/how-can-i-convert-bitmapimage-to-icon)), but I would call it pain.

NotifyIcon is not implemented in WPF, so I suggest to try this [solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon).

More detais: [Can I use NotifyIcon in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674761/can-i-use-notifyicon-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the .ico file in your solution and point the reference to it something like this

Try doing this

```
ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"pack://application:,,,/Icon/main.ico");
```

Comment: It gives me same error: XamlParseException, I have added this ison already as project icon.

Comment: I should replace this commas with something or just copy like that? In this format it's return still same error as before.

Comment: Anyway i just dont want it to be static string because when I send this app for anybody it cant be run.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, anyway this post is a duplicate i flagged it already. Sorry for duplicating.