# How to convert Bitmap to BitmapImage for WPF VB.NET

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, bitmap, bitmapimage

I'm trying to convert a Bitmap to a BitmapImage in WPF. Basically, I'm starting with a Bitmap created in memory (from another process) and I need to use it elsewhere, but as a BitmapImage.

I found this answer [question 6484357](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484357/converting-bitmapimage-to-bitmap-and-vice-versa), but the author's function Bitmap2BitmapImage does not work (at least in DotNet4.5) as there is no such method called Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap - so no luck there (at least no way to convert to a VB.Net equivalent function).

Comment: Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap is in `System.Windows.Interop.Imaging`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorporating question 6484357 and translated to vb.net

```
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Interop
Imports System.Windows.Media.Imaging

Namespace StackConsoleTesting
Class Program

    Private Function BitmapImage2Bitmap(bitmapImage As BitmapImage) As Bitmap
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Images/test.png", UriKind.Relative));

        Using outStream = New MemoryStream()
            Dim enc As BitmapEncoder = New BmpBitmapEncoder()
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage))
            enc.Save(outStream)
            Dim bitmap As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream)

            Return New Bitmap(bitmap)
        End Using
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")> _
    Public Shared Function DeleteObject(hObject As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    Private Function Bitmap2BitmapImage(bitmap As Bitmap) As BitmapImage
        Dim hBitmap As IntPtr = bitmap.GetHbitmap()
        Dim retval As BitmapImage

        Try

            Dim bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions())

            Dim encoder = New BmpBitmapEncoder()
            Dim memoryStream = New MemoryStream()

            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource))
            encoder.Save(memoryStream)

            retval.BeginInit()
            retval.StreamSource = New MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray())
            retval.EndInit()

            memoryStream.Close()

        Return retval
    End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: I was importing System.Drawing.Imaging, so I had to change Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap to 
System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap

Comment: Spoke too soon. The DirectCast generates an error.
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage'."

Comment: I'm working on getting this to work properly, the referenced question (marked as a duplicate) creates a bitmapsource - that works, but the question was to create a BITMAP  - the functions provided do not work as coded (at least not in VB.Net) - I should have a working function soon once I research a bit more.

Comment: See correction above at the end of Trae's post  (not sure why, but the edit did not show up as a code block). It's fully tested and works fine.

Comment: I changed the JpegBitmapEncoder to BmpBitmapEncoder for performance

Dim encoder = New BmpBitmapEncoder()

Comment: @MC9000 Updated the answer with your performance enhancement.