# Show bitmap as image

Tags: c#, wpf

I have qrcode generator (I used ZXing.QrCode)

```
public Bitmap GenerateQR(int width, int height, string text)
    {
        var bw = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter();
        var encOptions = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions() { Width = width, Height = height, Margin = 0 };
        bw.Options = encOptions;
        bw.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
        var result = new Bitmap(bw.Write(text));

        return result;
    }
```

Now I wonted to show qr code in new window so i call:

```
var window = new Zeszycik.View.show(GenerateQR(300,300,"some txt")); 
window.Show();
```

But I don't know how to show qrcode in new window

```
public show(Bitmap qrcode)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        print(qrcode);
    }
    private void print(Bitmap img)
    {
       image.Source = img; //error
    }
```

Comment: The *Write(string)* method of `ZXing.Presentation.BarcodeWriter` will return a `BitmapSource` object which you can directly assign to image.Source. No need to do any Bitmap-->BitmapSource conversion then. (ZXing.Presentation.BarcodeWriter is provided by the *zxing.presentation.dll* assembly which should be part of the ZXing.NET package)

Comment: If I do what u say I have an error in `var result = new BitmapSource(bw.Write(text));` _Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource'_

Comment: I said *ZXing.Presentation.BarcodeWriter.Write(string)* will **return** a BitmapSource object. I did not say that you should do "new BitmapSource(...)".

Answer (score 0):

Image Source property is of type **`ImageSource`** but **`Bitmap`** doesn't derive from ImageSource so you need to convert it to an instance of ImageSource which can either be **`BitmapImage`** or **`BitmapSource`**.

Now, to convert Bitmap to BitmapSource, you can refer to this link [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6484754/632337). For sake of completeness of answer I will post the answer from the link here:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

private BitmapSource Bitmap2BitmapSource(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitMap();
    BitmapSource retval;

    try
    {
        retval = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                     hBitmap,
                     IntPtr.Zero,
                     Int32Rect.Empty,
                     BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
    finally
    {
        DeleteObject(hBitmap); //Necessary to avoid memory leak.
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Now you can set Image source like this:

```
image.Source = Bitmap2BitmapSource(img);
```